# Two way data binding of specific attribute of LiveData object

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata

I have a problem with two way data binding using LiveData. I have a ViewModel with a `MutableLiveData<Ingredient> ingredient`. In the XML layout I would like to initialize `EditText` view with `ingredient.title` attribute. I tried this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="UpdateIngredientViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/updateIngredient_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:text="@={viewModel.ingredient.getValue().title}"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/updateIngredient_label"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:hint="@string/Title"
            android:inputType="text"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

So using this line `android:text="@={viewModel.ingredient.getValue().title}"` initialize the title value of Ingredient, but if I change the text in `EditText` and rotate the display for example, I don't get the changed value, but the initialized one instead. Could somebody help me with this, please?
This is my ViewModel:

```
public class UpdateIngredientViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<Ingredient> ingredient;

    public UpdateIngredientViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public LiveData<Ingredient> getIngredient() {
        if (ingredient == null) {
            ingredient = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }
        return ingredient;
    }

    public void setIngredient(Ingredient ingredient) {
            this.ingredient.setValue(ingredient);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is the Ingredient class:

```
public class Ingredient {
    @SerializedName("ingredient_ID")
    private int ingredient_ID;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

    public Ingredient(int ingredient_ID, String title) {
        this.ingredient_ID = ingredient_ID;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getIngredient_ID() {
        return ingredient_ID;
    }

    public void setIngredient_ID(int ingredient_ID) {
        this.ingredient_ID = ingredient_ID;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

I also tried to change `EditText` attribute like this `android:text="@={viewModel.ingredient.title}"`, but it seems it works the same way as in original post.

Comment: What does `Ingredient` look like?

Comment: @CommonsWare I provided the `Ingredient` in edit of the question

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `setTitle()`, is it triggered by the two-way data binding? If it is, then perhaps you are somehow reinitializing the `MutableLiveData` in `UpdateIngredientViewModel` after the configuration change. If the breakpoint is not being set, then the problem lies in the two-way data binding.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh my bad. I was getting the Ingredient from server and I called that method from ViewModel on every configuration change which overwrite the Livedata. Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two-way data binding can update your model. However, there are two problems with your approach.

The one that you ran into is that `MutableLiveData` is not magic, and if you replace the value, it will happily follow orders. Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55986883/two-way-data-binding-of-specific-attribute-of-livedata-object?noredirect=1#comment98622981_55986883), you were replacing the value in the `MutableLiveData` after a configuration change, and that was oblivious to what the user entered.

The other problem is that while the `MutableLiveData` will hold your revised `Ingredient`, any other observers of that `MutableLiveData` will not know about the change. You are modifying the model *in situ*, and the `MutableLiveData` does not know about that and cannot let other observers know. This is why I prefer to use `MutableLiveData` objects that are as immutable as possible (e.g., Kotlin `val`), and as a result I skip two-way data binding.

Comment: I think I don't get everything you mentioned in your answer. If I would skip two-way data binding, how should I store the actual value of edittext so I won't lose it on configuration changes? I thought handling it using two-way data binding is the best practice now. At least better than handling it with Bundles. Am I wrong? I bind the value of Ingredient from server and always have the actual value in the edittext, so when I press an update button, I use the MutableLiveData Ingredient for it.

Comment: @Braintertainer: "If I would skip two-way data binding, how should I store the actual value of edittext so I won't lose it on configuration changes?" -- it is automatically retained as part of the saved instance state `Bundle`, if you're not doing anything to interfere with it. And the saved instance state `Bundle` also retains the value across process terminations, beyond just configuration changes. "I thought handling it using two-way data binding is the best practice now" -- I do not see much evidence that many people are using it. You're welcome to do so, just beware of the problems.

Comment: then I'm doing something wrong. I've read that all I need to do to save `EditText`'s value is to provide it with an ID. My `EditText` has an ID and there are just 3 methods I call in a `Fragment`: `onCreate`, `onCreateView`, `onViewCreated`...I call `super` on both `onCreate` and `onViewCreated` but I always lose the value in `EditText`. Could I ask you for a help so I won't need to do this two-way data binding just for that? Thank you

Comment: @Braintertainer: Temporarily remove your binding expressions from your layout. Type something into the `EditText`, then undergo a configuration change. If what you typed is retained, then there is a timing issue with respect to the data binding (I've run into that before, but I don't have the solution at hand right now). If what you typed is not retained, then something else is going on.